# Simulate Activity/Fragment restore state in recreation with ViewModel using Espresso

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I`m using Espresso in Instrumented Tests of my mvvm app, and nearly everything is working just fine. But i want to cover the case of activity store/restore state during activity recreation.
And i'm using this to simulate this scenario:

`InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()
               .runOnMainSync { activity.recreate() }`

And it works, `onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle)` is called and also `onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)` with `savedInstanceState` with my saved variables.

The problem is that `onCleared` of my ViewModel is not being called, because it's not being destroyed during the `activity.recreate()` call.

The main point here is when the Activity is recreated it's receiving the same ViewModel instance created earlier, and i don't want it to happen. I want it to work in same way when i manually turn *Don't keep activities* on.

Is there a way to simulate both Activity/Fragment and ViewModel being destroyed using Espresso?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm trying to solve the exact same problem.